# PHP $_SERVER[] change url

Tags: php, file-upload

I have used the a jquery script that is used to upload files:
http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

I have download the source code and upload it to my server.

The script has one point that indicates the directory or the path for the files that are to be uploaded

```
'script_url' => $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
            'upload_dir' => dirname(__FILE__).'/files/',
            'upload_url' => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/files/',
```

The full path to this script is `/home/youthcen/public_html/uploader/example/upload.php` from my web server root.

I want to change the upload destination to /home/youthcen/public_html/media/ instead of `/home/youthcen/public_html/uploader/files/` that is set by the sript to upload files there

Comment: Please give us only the relevant piece of code. Also tell us exactly where the problem and what have you tried.

Comment: -1 Please clearify your question and only place relevant code.

Comment: looks like /media/ is in the same level as /files/. So I'd change that to just /media/. this is just a guess, though, since the way you described your problem is really vague.

Comment: Well i updated the question, to be more specific :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is media on the same level as files?

If yes, replace "/files/" with "/media/", if it is below as you say, try replacing with "/../media/" instead.

Just a guess.

Comment: Yes it did the job. I was missing the first /../ . I used it with ../ that was wrong. Anyway thank you